# How do I completely clear a SQLite3 database without deleting the database file?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For unit testing purposes I need to completely reset/clear SQLite3 databases. All databases are created in memory rather than on the file system when running the test suite so I can't delete any files. Additionally, several instances of a class will be referencing the database simultaneously, so I can't just create a new database in memory and assign it to a variable.

Currently my workaround for clearing a database is to read all the table names from `sqlite_master` and drop them. This is not the same as completely clearing the database though, since meta data and other things I don't understand will probably remain.

Is there a clean and simple way, like a single query, to clear a SQLite3 database? If not, what would have to be done to an existing database to make it identical to a completely new database?

---

In case it's relevant, I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 with [sqlite3-ruby](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby) version 1.3.7 and SQLite3 version 3.8.2.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use **deleteDatabase(String name)** in order to
Delete an existing private SQLiteDatabase associated with this Context's application package? you can find it here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html

Comment: @Ali: Sorry, I'm not using Java nor developing for Android. See my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works without deleting the file and without closing the db connection:

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
DELETE FROM sqlite_master;
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
VACUUM;
PRAGMA integrity_check;
```

Another option, if possible to call the C API directly, is by using the `SQLITE_DBCONFIG_RESET_DATABASE`:

```c
sqlite3_db_config(db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_RESET_DATABASE, 1, 0);
sqlite3_exec(db, "VACUUM", 0, 0, 0);
sqlite3_db_config(db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_RESET_DATABASE, 0, 0);
```

Here is the [reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbconfig_defensive.html#sqlitedbconfigresetdatabase)

Answer (score 4):

**The simple and quick way**

If you use in-memory database, the fastest and most reliable way is to close and re-establish sqlite connection. It flushes any database data and also per-connection settings.

If you want to have some kind of "reset" function, you must assume that no other threads can interrupt that function - otherwise any method will fail. Therefore even you have multiple threads working on that database, there need to be a "stop the world" mutex (or something like that), so the reset can be performed. While you have exclusive access to the database connection - why not closing and re-opening it?

**The hard way**

If there are some other limitations and you cannot do it the way above, then you were already pretty close to have a complete solution. If your threads don't touch pragmas explicitly, then only "schema_version" pragma can be changed silently, but if your threads can change pragmas, well, then you have to go through the list on http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#toc and write "reset" function which will set each and every pragma value to it's initial value (you need to read default values at the begining).

Note, that pragmas in SQLite can be divided to 3 groups:

1. defined initially, immutable, or very limited mutability
2. defined dynamically, per connection, mutable
3. defined dynamically, per database, mutable

Group 1 are for example page_size, page_count, encoding, etc. Those are definied at database creation moment and usualle cannot be modified later, with some exceptions. For example page_size can be changed prior to "VACUUM", so the new page size will be set then. The page_count cannot be changed by user, but it changes automatically when adding data (obviously). The encoding is defined at creation time and cannot be modified later.
You should not need to reset pragmas from group 1.

Group 2 are for example cache_size, recursive_triggers, jurnal_mode, foreign_keys, busy_timeout, etc. These pragmas are always set to defaults when opening new connection to the database. If you don't disconnect, you will need to reset those to defaults manually.

Group 3 are for example schema_version, user_version, maybe some others, you need to look it up. Those will also need manual reset. If you disconnect from in-memory database, the database gets destroyed, so then you don't need to reset those.

Comment: Can I `db.close()` a connection and reconnect using the same `Database` instance? My issue is that I have multiple of references to the database from various places in my code.

Comment: According to http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/SQLite/Database.html#M000066 the `open()` will return new instance, so unfortunately no, you cannot just `db.close()`. I see 2 possibilities now: 1) go with "the hard way", or 2) write yourself a simple wrapper class, which will have the same interface (instance methods) and put the actual `db` object inside, so when you call `close()` and `open()` it will internally close and create new instance, but the outer object will remain the same.

Comment: Had to call Database.EnsureCreated after reseting the connection.  Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty memory database.
2. Use the backup API to copy that database over the actual database.

In the case of sqlite3-ruby, see `test/test_backup.rb` for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

and

```
DROP TABLE
```

Comment: This is my exact current workaround. Did you read my whole question? This won't reset pragmas.