# Golang: Integration tests hitting the same db instance even upon db.Close()

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I have a test suite that uses an in-memory sqlite instance to run db queries. After adding some tests, I suddenly started to get tons of "UNIQUE constraint failed..." errors in every line that tries to perform an insertion. That makes it *seem* like all my tests are connecting to, writing to, and reading from the same db instance. Here's how the test db instance is produced

```
const DBProvider = "sqlite3"

// DBConnection is the connection string to use for testing
const DBConnection = "file::memory:?cache=shared"

// NewMigratedDB returns a new connection to a migrated database
func NewMigratedDB(provider string, connection string, models ...interface{}) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    db, err := gorm.Open(provider, connection)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    db = db.AutoMigrate(models...)
    if db.Error != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

And here's how it's used in tests -

```
    db, err := test.NewMigratedDB(test.DBProvider, test.DBConnection, models...)
    defer db.Close()
    // read/write anything
```

How can I make each call to NewMigratedDB to produce a *different* instance of SQLite that only listens to queries from the unit test that instantiated it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be helpful to see a full example of how you're using `NewMigratedDB` in a test. Here's my suggestions based on what I can see (and what I can't).

### Setup a Named In-memory Database

Each of your unit tests *appear* to be using the same in-memory copy of the SQLite database. Use the following syntax to create separate named instances of the in-memory database. If your tests are running in parallel, they'd most likely share the same database. Replace `test1` with a unique name for each test that is running in parallel (see [the sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for more info).

> If two or more distinct but shareable in-memory databases are needed in a single process, then the `mode=memory` query parameter can be used with a URI filename to create a named in-memory database

```
const DBConnection = "file:test1?mode=memory&cache=shared"
```

### Open and Close Between Tests

You also need to make sure you're initializing a fresh database per-test, not once at the top of your testing function. For example:

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    // Don't initialize it here
    
    t.Run("test1", func(t *testing.T) {
        db, err := test.NewMigratedDB(test.DBProvider, test.DBConnection, models...)
        defer db.Close()
        // Do something
    })
    t.Run("test2", func(t *testing.T) {
        db, err := test.NewMigratedDB(test.DBProvider, test.DBConnection, models...)
        defer db.Close()
        // Do something
    })
}
```

If you are opening and closing before and after each test and you do not have any tests running concurrently that also connect to sqlite, then [closing the connection should clear the sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549094/13906951) and you don't need to use named, in-memory databases as a fresh database will be re-created on the next call to `gorm.Open`. There's a lot of "ifs" there so pick your poison.